# Random series convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-functions

Let $\{\eta_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a family of i.i.d. random variables with parameter $p \in [0,1]$ Bernoulli distribution.

Let $S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \eta_k$. How to prove that $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\eta_n - p}{S_n + 1}$$ converge almost surely?

I tried to use the fact that $\frac{S_n}{n}$ goes to $p$ a.s. because we now that $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\eta_n - p}{n}$ converges a.s., but i don't get success...

Thanks!

Comment: Isn’t it true that with probability $p$, the first term in the sum is $-p/0$ which is undefined? Are we conditioning away from that somehow?

Comment: To avoid this problem change $S_n$ for $S_n + 1$. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use the fact that $S_n/n\to p$ a.s. to say that a.s., for any fixed $p'<p<p''$, there exists $N$ sufficiently large such that $n\geq N$ implies $np'<S_n<np''$? So then a.s. the tail of your series is up to constant factors arbitrarily close to $1/p$ equal to the tail of the series that you claim you know converges almost surely? You can then take $p',p''\to p$.

Comment: I tried exactly this, but we have negative terms in a random order...